# Localhost apache server uses different install of ruby. How can I change it?

Tags: ruby, apache, rubygems, wamp

There is an installation of ruby located in my ~Library folder, and an installation of ruby in my local user directory.

When I run ruby commands and install gems, it is the one in the local directory that gets used. However I want to install gems for the ruby that is sitting in the Library folder, or get WAMP and the localhost to start using the ruby version in my local directory.

I've tried navigation to the gem script in the ~Library folder and installing gems using that explicit path, but it only installs them to the local user version. Why does localhost use the ruby sitting in the Library file? And how can I change it to use the local user's ruby, or failing that, how can I install gems for the ruby sitting in the library folder?

Thanks

**On the localhost: gem environment**

'RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dzoo/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - universal-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:

  - /Library/Ruby/Gems'...

**In terminal: gem environment**

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.4
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dzoo/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dzoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dzoo/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-12
- GEM PATHS:

  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - /Users/dzoo/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/server
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/client
  - /Users/dzoo/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/server
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/client
  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin
  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin
  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
  - /Users/dzoo/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/server
  - /Applications/PlasticSCM/client
  - /usr/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /sbin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /usr/local/db/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.1/bin
  - /Users/dzoo/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52
  - /opt/X11/bin
  - /Users/dzoo/.rvm/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin

Comment: It's not wise to mess with the system ruby. [Phusion Passenger](https://rvm.io/deployment/passenger) seems to be the recommended solution. If you insist on altering the system ruby, first run `rvm use system`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That helped a lot